# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function error in ASP .NET MVC View file

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function is the error. 
All the required files have been added and in order too.
Tried clearing cache and all that stuff but still not able to get this working. Is it something stupid that i might be doing or am i missing something.
I tried adding CDN from many sources, directly using the file from source but to no effect.Using Id 'draggable' instead of class. Can someone pls help
This is the updated code
`

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( function() {
          $(".draggable").draggable();
      } );
    </script>
     <div class="draggable col-md-6">Test</div>
```

`
Update :

The code is running in an Index file in the Views folder of an MVC project.I dont know if this information will be useful

Comment: don't see any issue with above code. Are you sure that you have this much code only. Otherwise share the complete code.

Comment: Shoudn't this much information be enough, not that i have any problem to show that but its just a plain html index page which i think wont have any effect on the js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in ASP .NET MVC there is a default line of code

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: true)
```

which disables all other scripts that comes in views
To solve this just add the script file in the section scripts as so

```
@section scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
}
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="draggable col-md-6">Test</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your attempt to try this out but the problem wasnt the code

Answer (score 1):

draggable is misspelled, also should be referred with a . instead of a # as long as is a class, and not a id. Try this code instead:

```
 <style>
        .draggable {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 0.5em;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( function() {
          $(".draggable").draggable();
      } );
    </script>
     <div class="draggable">
      Hola
     </div>
```

Comment: I dont think the correcting the CSS would solve the issue here.(tried it anyway) . But thanx for trying , the issue is something else. Infact the CSS is not required here.

Comment: Try loading the libraries just as I put them. In many browsers, if you have a object before its declaration loads, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

Page was referring to - Two jquery.js references.

one was in the Master Page. (layout page) with the old version. and at body footer.

So I have removed the old one and have given the reference to a new version in the header part.